# How to add TwiML to TwiML Bin via Twilio Api only?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am automating many Twilio procedures and want to create a TwiML file and add to a subaccount's twiML bin. Is there any way to work with the the twiML bin via Twilio's api? I have looked at their extensive docs and cannot see anything that would help me. I do not want to use the Twilio console for this task.

Comment: You can use Twilio Functions instead, which does provide an API. https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions-assets-api/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for creating, reading, updating or deleting Twiml Bins. As Levi stated, you will want to use Twilio serverless Functions instead, [Functions & Assets (API-only)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions-assets-api), and/or host the application logic on your side and [programmatically update the respective webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource).

[Locally Develop and Debug Twilio Functions in Node.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8s8cwjh4_7Q&list=PLqrz4nXepkz6fX9ynQpCqgScE8wmPE9VY)